# Which one is the suitable Debian iso for desktop?

Tags: debian

There are so many iso files in Debian website that I am really getting confused. How do I choose from them?

- I used Ubuntu before.
- I want to install Debian to my desktop
- I want Gnome or KDE to be my DE
- I downloaded a version called xxxxxxx-CD-1.iso but it doesnt seem to have a GUI

Comment: If you have a network connection, use the netinst iso. It does a basic installation for you; then you can download whatever else you want after that.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate, at least not of the linked duplicate (which is specifically about the 31-CD set of Debian 5). Nowadays, the best option is the netinst CD as others have said; but there are also different "CD 1" options (see [the downloadable CDs](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.6.0/amd64/iso-cd/)): GNOME (the default), KDE, LXDE or Xfce.

Answer (score 3):

Use netinst, you can choose desktop environment at the end of install.
http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current/amd64/iso-cd/

Comment: I recently installed Debian via the "Net Install" ISO "burned" to a bootable USB pen. Indeed it will give you the option to install a desktop environment such as GNOME or MATE.